# Accepting incoming requests asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, asyncsocket

I have identified a bottleneck in my TCP application that I have simplified for the sake of this question.

I have a `MyClient` class, that represents when a client connects; also I have a `MyWrapper` class, that represents a client that fulfill some conditions. If a `MyClient`fulfill some conditions, it qualifies for wrapper.

I want to expose an method that allows the caller to await a `MyWrapper`, and that method should handle the negotiation and rejection of invalid `MyClients`:

```
public static async Task StartAccepting(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var wrapper = await AcceptWrapperAsync(token);

        HandleWrapperAsync(wrapper);
    }
}
```

Therefore `AcceptWrapperAsync` awaits a valid wrapper, and `HandleWrapperAsync` handles the wrapper asynchronously without blocking the thread, so `AcceptWrapperAsync` can get back to work as fast as it can.

How that method works internally is something like this:

```
public static async Task<MyWrapper> AcceptWrapperAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var client = await AcceptClientAsync();
        if (IsClientWrappable(client))
            return new MyWrapper(client);
    }
    return null;
}

public static async Task<MyClient> AcceptClientAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return new MyClient();
}

private static Boolean IsClientWrappable(MyClient client)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    return true;
}
```

This code simulates that there is a client connection every second, and that it takes half a second to checkout if the connection is suitable for a wrapper. `AcceptWrapperAsync` loops till a valid wrapper is generated, and then returns.

This approach, that works well, has a flaw. During the time that `IsClientWrappable` is executing, no further clients can be accepted, creating a bottleneck when lot of clients are trying to connect at the same time. I am afraid that in real life, if the server goes down while having lot of clients connected, the going up is not gonna be nice because all of them will try to connect at the same time. I know that is very difficult to connect all of them at the same time, but I would like to speed up the connection process.

Making `IsClientWrappable` async, would just ensure that the executing thread is not blocked till the negotiation finishes, but the execution flow is blocked anyway.

How could I improve this approach to continuously accept new clients but still be able of awaiting a wrapper using `AcceptWrapperAsync`?

Comment: This seems to be a good use case for **Reactive Extensions (Rx)**

Comment: Rx for this would be an overkill. It seems that Dataflow makes more sense.

Comment: With RX you push data into a subscriber, whereas with DataFlow you push data into a consumer. :)

Comment: Well, it seems that RX is much more than that. Dataflow is just a collection of classes to work asynchronously :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TPL Dataflow to the rescue. I have created a "producer/consumer" object with two queues that:

1. accepts inputs from "producer" and stores it in the "in" queue.
2. a internal asynchronous task read from the "in" queue and process the input in parallel with a given maximum degree of parallelism.
3. put the processed item in the "out" queue afterwards. Result or Exception.
4. accepts a consumer to `await` an item. Then can check if the processing was successful or not.

I have done some testing and it seems to work fine, I want to do more testing though:

```
public sealed class ProcessingResult<TOut> 
    where TOut : class
{
    public TOut Result { get; internal set; }
    public Exception Error { get; internal set; }
}

public abstract class ProcessingBufferBlock<TIn,TOut> 
    where TIn:class 
    where TOut:class
{
    readonly BufferBlock<TIn> _in;
    readonly BufferBlock<ProcessingResult<TOut>> _out;
    readonly CancellationToken _cancellation;
    readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public ProcessingBufferBlock(Int32 boundedCapacity, Int32 degreeOfParalellism, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        _cancellation = cancellation;
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(degreeOfParalellism);
        var options = new DataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = boundedCapacity, CancellationToken = cancellation };
        _in = new BufferBlock<TIn>(options);
        _out = new BufferBlock<ProcessingResult<TOut>>(options);
        StartReadingAsync();
    }

    private async Task StartReadingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        while (!_cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var incoming = await _in.ReceiveAsync(_cancellation);
            ProcessThroughGateAsync(incoming);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessThroughGateAsync(TIn input)
    {
        _semaphore.Wait(_cancellation);
        Exception error=null;
        TOut result=null;
        try
        {
            result = await ProcessAsync(input);                   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(result!=null || error!=null)
                _out.Post(new ProcessingResult<TOut>() { Error = error, Result = result });
            _semaphore.Release(1);
        }
    }

    protected abstract Task<TOut> ProcessAsync(TIn input);

    public void Post(TIn item)
    {
        _in.Post(item);
    }

    public Task<ProcessingResult<TOut>> ReceiveAsync()
    {
        return _out.ReceiveAsync();
    }
}
```

So the example I used on the OP would be something like this:

```
public class WrapperProcessingQueue : ProcessingBufferBlock<MyClient, MyWrapper>
{
    public WrapperProcessingQueue(Int32 boundedCapacity, Int32 degreeOfParalellism, CancellationToken cancellation)
        : base(boundedCapacity, degreeOfParalellism, cancellation)
    { }

    protected override async Task<MyWrapper> ProcessAsync(MyClient input)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        if (input.Id % 3 == 0)
            return null;
        return new MyWrapper(input);
    }
}
```

And then I could add `MyClient` objects to that queue as fast as I get them, they would be processed in parallel, and the consumer would await for the ones that pass the filter.

As I said, I want to do more testing but any feedback will be very welcomed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
//this loop must never be blocked
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var client = await AcceptClientAsync();
    HandleClientAsync(client); //must not block
}

Task HandleClientAsync(Client client) {
    if (await IsClientWrappableAsync(client)) //make async as well, don't block
        await HandleWrapperAsync(new MyWrapper(client));
}
```

This way you move the `IsClientWrappable` logic out of the accept loop and into the background async workflow.

If you do not wish to make `IsClientWrappable` non-blocking, just wrap it with `Task.Run`. It is essential that `HandleClientAsync` does not block so that its caller doesn't either.

Comment: I cannot do that, as I said, I have to provide an awaitable `AcceptWrapperAsync`

Comment: Ok, I'd look into Rx in that case. It looks like you have a stream of incoming clients, that need to be filtered and converted to wrapped clients. All in an async way. Rx can do that but I'm not familiar enough with that.